Azure SSIS integration runtime fails with error .Reason: Azure Active Directory only authentication is enabled
I am trying to setup Azure SSIS integration runtime in adf. I have setup the Azure SQL server and Azure database to host the SSISDB and checked "Allow Azure services and resources access to this server", and selected Microsoft Entra authentication only. Added myself as the server admin.
I have created a AAD security group (datafactorysg) and added adf managed identity to that group and myself.
Logged into Azure SQL server and have the below script to provide access to the above security group to Azure SQl server.
USE MASTER
CREATE USER [datafactorysg] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER [datafactorysg]
USE SQLTEST
CREATE USER [datafactorysg] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
--Grant appropriate role to Azure Data Factory based on your needs.
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [datafactorysg];
I created a Azure SSIS runtime and provided the SQL end point and Use Microsoft Entra authentication with the system managed identity for Data Factory and test connection passes. But it tries to start the SSIS integration services fails with the below error.
Error code: AzureSqlConnectionFailure. Error message: Failed to connect to Azure SQL DB server due to sql error '18456', message: Login failed for user '***'. Reason: Azure Active Directory only authentication is enabled. Please contact your system administrator. Please add your ADF MSI into an AAD group with access permissions to your catalog database server.. Activity ID: c9bd5f3c-d903-4dd9-bc9f-564f7a83b7b6
Could somebody please help.
thanks
Tried all possible. Same error
